# Play 2.0 - access running (Fake)Application from scala console

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm just getting started with the Play Framework 2.0 (using current trunk 2.1-SNAPSHOT, Scala) and I'm finding it very useful to experiment with the Scala API in the `play console`.

For some things, however, for example stuff that depends on `play.libs.WS` API, I'm getting the `There is no started application` error. Fair enough, but I can't figure out how to set up a fake one up to use from the console, or whether this is even possible.

It seems that `play.api.test._` isn't even accessible from the console. Any suggestions?

Update: Thanks to @charroch, I needed to run `play test:console`, so I can now do:

```
import play.api.test.Helpers.running
import play.api.test.FakeApplication

val res = running(FakeApplication()) { 
    MyWebservice.someFunction()  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `test:console` to start the console with test api in classpath

You need to have   `running(FakeApplication) {...}` in your test as per:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTest