# How do I run a comand line scala script that uses Play Framework app database?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have this on my `app/scripts` folder (I created this folder inside `app/`). I'm not sure how I can properly set the classpath here, thus I didn't even run this to know if it will actually connect to the database. How can I run this in a clean way from the command line?

```
package scripts

import scala.collection.TraversableOnce
import scala.collection.generic.SeqForwarder
import scala.io.Source
import scala.slick.jdbc.{StaticQuery => Q}
import scala.slick.session.Session
import scala.slick.session.Database
import play.api.db.DB
import tables.Campeonatos
import tables.Jogos
import org.postgresql.Driver
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

// ...

class InsertJogosCSV extends App {
  val dao = new DAO()
  val application = FakeApplication()

  def insertJogos(csv: CSV)(implicit s: Session) = {
    val times = dao.getTimeIdByNameMap
    var count = 0
    csv foreach { case cols =>
      count += 1
      dao.insertJogo(cols, times)
    }
    count
  }

  val csvFilePath: String = args(0)
  val csv = new CSV(csvFilePath)
  csv.printLines
  running(application) {
    val realDatabase = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource()(application))
    implicit val s = realDatabase.createSession
    insertJogos(csv)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the `play test:console` command at the root of your app. First you could probably move the code into a main method rather than extending `App`:

```
class InsertJogosCSV {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val dao = new DAO()
        val application = FakeApplication()

        def insertJogos(csv: CSV)(implicit s: Session) = {....}

        ....
    }
}
```

then run the `play test:console` command and do the following

```
scala> import scripts.InsertJogosCSV
import scripts.InsertJogosCSV

scala> val insert = new InsertJogosCSV()
insert: scripts.InsertJogosCSV = scripts.InsertJogosCSV@7d5f9d2b

scala> insert.main
res0: .....
```

The `play test:console` by default adds everything from the app folder to your class path as well as the `FakeApplication` context that you need for your script. Hope that helps.

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11297578/2556428

Comment: That surely helps. I started learning how to create SBT tasks to perform this. SBT is so complicated that I'm still reading the docs to find out the simplest way to handle filepath arguments on tasks.

I'll be using the test:console for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've made a blog post explaining my final solution. Should work as an answer to the question.

http://blog.felipe.rs/2014/05/15/run-maintenance-scripts-in-the-context-of-a-running-play-framework-application/

Comment: @Alex http://blog.felipe.rs/2014/05/15/run-maintenance-scripts-in-the-context-of-a-running-play-framework-application/

Comment: @philinx both.  Did you move the entry or was the server stuck? Anyway consider the issue gone. Thanks for fixing

Comment: @Alex the day in the date was off-by-one. I think that's due to some bug related to living in different time zones :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using another approach , for similar task.

Create empty subproject in main playframework project.

In build.sbt it looks like

```
// Main project
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).enablePlugins(com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb)
// Utils sbt project with scripts
lazy val sjutil = project.aggregate(root).dependsOn(root)
```

and sjutil/build.sbt like normal sbt project with extra deps if needed, for me it was akka-remote

```
name := "sjutil"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies +=   "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.3.4"
```

You can place some App direct in sjutil/ folder

sjutil/actorsstarter.scala:

```
object actorsstarter {
  lazy val logger = play.api.Logger("actorsstarter")
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
     // read config from conf/application.conf of main project
     val remoteConfig = ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("botstarter")

     val system = ActorSystem("application",remoteConfig)
     val path = "akka.tcp://application@127.0.0.1:2553/user"
     ....
     logger.info("Started")
  }
}
```

after that you can run this script with:

```
./activator sjutil/run
```

and make everything you can do with normal project: stage, dist and etc.