# How do I create a runnable script from within a Play Framework project?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I currently have a play framework project with a ton of code (utils, modules, etc) that I want to utilize in a runnable script (or program/main). My understanding is that if I make the script a sub project then I can't utilize the code from the parent project. I need to utilize the code from the parent project.

I am able to just put the script somewhere in within the app directory and do something like, for example, sbt run-main com.foo.bar.Foobar. Unfortunately this (obviously) doesn't bring in all of Play. No database, no Global, no configurations, etc etc etc. Basically it doesn't bootstrap play.

Is there any way to accomplish what i'm trying to do besides taking my parent project and making all of the code that I want to share a sub project also?

Edit: I have attempted to use the solution found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583244/how-do-i-run-a-comand-line-scala-script-that-uses-play-framework-app-database) but it causes an error stating that there is no application running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a comand line scala script that uses Play Framework app database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583244/how-do-i-run-a-comand-line-scala-script-that-uses-play-framework-app-database)

Comment: Unforutnately that solution is not working. I'm unsure if that's becasue it is outdated or something else but it doesn't work. It keeps just saying "There is no started application"

Comment: I'm not sure why someone has marked this as a duplicate and is forcing me to mark my question as "That other question's solution solved my problem". It helped me solve my problem but, at least for me, it was an incomplete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the best solution I found in　[How do I run a comand line scala script that uses Play Framework app database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583244/how-do-i-run-a-comand-line-scala-script-that-uses-play-framework-app-database)（http://blog.felipe.rs/2014/05/14/run-maintenance-scripts-in-the-context-of-a-running-play-framework-application/）I had to modify it in the following way.

```
def importJogosFromCSV(csvFilePath: String) = {
    db withSession { implicit s: Session =>
      JogosCSVImporter.importJogos(csvFilePath)
    }
  }
```

Was changed to:

```
def importJogosFromCSV(csvFilePath: String) = {
    running(application) {
      db withSession { implicit s: Session =>
        JogosCSVImporter.importJogos(csvFilePath)
      }
    }
  }
```

Ultimately I needed to add running(application)
I'm using specs2 with play 2.3.x

Comment: That blog link is dead :(